# Tell whether route is behind firewall in Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, cookies

I'm currently writing an event listener in Symfony2, which listens for the `kernel.response` event, and adds a cookie to it if: a) a user is logged in, and b) no such cookie currently exists. It takes the service container as an argument.

However, I'm getting an error when the listener responds to events not behind a firewall (such as those in the dev toolbar) since the token is empty and an `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` is thrown. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell whether the route is behind a firewall or not. Could anyone help?

**Code**

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    // does the request have a device cookie?
    if ($this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
        && !$this->getRequest()->cookies->has(DeviceManager::COOKIE_PREFIX.'id')) {
        // no. Create one.
        $DeviceManager          =   $this->container->get('salus_user.device_manager');
        $Cookie                 =   $DeviceManager->createDeviceCookie();
        $Response               =   $event->getResponse();
        $Response->headers->setCookie($Cookie); // and save it
    }
    // else, yes, we don't need to do anything
}
```

**Error**

```
AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in classes.php line 2888:

The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

Comment: You can check if token exist:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if token exist:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    if (!$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
        return;
    }
    // Rest of code.
}
```